# Get variable from child project in subproject configuration in multi module gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi modul java project, where i want to create jar (bin,source,javadoc) and i have trouble getting variable, from subproejcts in subproject configuration.

this is my build.gradle file in the root project:

```
subprojects {
    /*...*/
        jar {
            manifest {
                attributes(
                    "Implementation-Title": project.name,
                    "Implementation-Version": project.version,
                    "Implementation-Vendor": "XXX",
                    "Main-Class": project.mainClassName
                )
            }
            include '**/**'
        }

    /*...*/
}
```

And this the build.gradle file one of the subproejcts:

```
    version = '1.2.0-SNAPSHOT'

    ext {
        mainClassName = "..."
    }
   /*...*/
```

when i want to run the build script i got the following exception:

> Could not get unknown property 'mainClassName' for object of type
>   org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest.

In the sub process configuration i have other task where i can easily access the proejct.version from each subproejct also project.name, and works well, and when i change a the `"Main-Class": project.mainClassName` to `"Main-Class": "i.hate.mylife.SoMuch"` the script runs perfectly.

In the subproejct i also try the followings

```
def mainClassName = "..."
project.ext{
    mainClassName = "..."
}
```

Is there any way in gradle to get variable of subroject from subproejcts in subproejct configuration?

In the subproject configuration  i also try the followings:

```
project.ext.mainClassName
project.ext.get("mainClassName")
```

And non of them work, when i try to run it, it's says:

> Cannot get property 'mainClassName' on extra properties extension as it does
>   not exist

Comment: why the two nested `subprojects` ?

Comment: @ToYonos copy paste error

Comment: why do you hate your life so much?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko i try to solve this trivial problem for hours now, i have read the documentation, many article, example project, and still no solution.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko why so cruel? I just found myself into the same shoes : doing something dynamically from root project into all subprojects, based on a sub-project property. should be trivial, but just like the OP I can't seem to be able to do it.

Comment: @Eugene no offence was intended. It was a joke about his class name. More than a year, and no answers... Let's start a bounty, shall we?

Comment: interesting, I did not need to do project -> subproject -> subproject; but instead only project -> subproject and this works just fine. it would be a lot easier if you could share a github repo where we could reproduce this may be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To override extra properties in subproject's build.gradle you must put your desired task (in this case the `jar task`) inside the `afterEvaluate` block.

root project build.gradle:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    ext {
        // the property that should be overridden in suproject's build.gradle
        mainClassName = ''
    }

    afterEvaluate {
        jar {
            manifest {
                attributes(
                    "Implementation-Title": project.name,
                    "Implementation-Version": project.version,
                    "Implementation-Vendor": "XXX",
                    "Main-Class": mainClassName
                )
            }
            include '**/**'
        }
    }
}
```

sub project build.gradle:

```
mainClassName = 'project.specific.Main'
ext.set("mainClassName", mainClassName)
```